# Expression Engine Apache and SSD

Tags: apache, codeigniter, expressionengine, solid-state-drive

Recently I've been working on an expression engine project that has a performance problem. On a test with 50 concurrent connections

1. Extremely high (100%) CPU usage
2. Low RAM usage (2 gigs out of 8)
3. Low CPU/RAM usage on the database

And the web server has 4 CPUs. Now, if I turn on the cache, the utilization is lower, but the content is such that dynamic caching had to be taken off. Now the expression engine is made up of templates that have to be read into memory and parsed. For those not familiar with expression engine, it is built using CodeIgniter.

My thinking is this that if Apache and the expression engine files were taken off HDD and put onto an SSD, I/O for the templates, it would be a lot faster and would lower the CPU utilization by Apache. Would this kind of performance improvement actually happen or would an SSD make no difference?

Answer (score 0):

SSD will always be faster then spinny turny disks where disk I/O is concerned, but it doesn't sound like that's where your bottleneck is.

You're not using RAM and as you correctly stated, the templates have to be parsed. You have 4 CPU's, but they may be from 1998 (we don't know). If they are more recent, it sounds like it should be more than enough for 50 concurrent connections, but you may be rendering the contents of the Library of Congress (again, we don't know).

You might get some benefit with [tag caching](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html#tag-caching) or some of the other techniques mentioned in [The Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html).

Also found this: http://eeinsider.com/articles/using-cache-wisely-with-expressionengine/